# Handle multiple simultaneous clients in python

Tags: python, sockets

I want to keep a socket open accepting unlimited number of clients, and be able to send independent data to each one, giving a ID for each client or something like that.

It seems easy in my mind but hard to put in the code as always.
I've tryed with asyncore but i cant get it to work, maybe im using the wrong plugin i don't know.

I hope someone can put me in the right way to do this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Either create a new thread for each client, use some [polling mechanism](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html), or a library like [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python twistted - http://twistedmatrix.com/